# Dart: compiler error when trying to access field after checking subtype in "if" statement

Tags: dart

In the example below, I get a compiler error when trying to access a subtype field after checking the type in an `if` statement. (tested on https://dartpad.dev/)

```dart
void main() {
  C().foo();
}

class C {
  Exception e = MyException();
  
  void foo() {
    if (e is MyException) {
      print(e.code);
      //     ^--- compiler error: 'code' isn't defined for the type 'Exception'
    }
  }
}

class MyException implements Exception {
  num code = 1;
}
```

However, after some rearranging the code below works. Is the error above deliberate or a compiler bug? If deliberate, what's the recommended pattern for this use case?

```dart
void main() {
  Exception e = MyException();
  if (e is MyException) {
    print(e.code);
  }
}

class MyException implements Exception {
  num code = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart does not promote instance fields, only local variables.

Promoting an instance field is not *sound*. Type promotion happens at compile-time when a check ensures that a local variable contains a value of a specific type, and it's only valid until you do something that can change the variable's value.

For instance fields, the compiler cannot know for certain that nothing writes the field from the outside, or whether a subclass overrides the field getter with something else.
It might be possible to find a few select cases where that's possible, but they are so few that it's easier to remember to always copy the value into a local variable before testing its type.

So, the recommended pattern is:

```dart
class C {
  Exception e = MyException();
  
  void foo() {
    var e = this.e; // Local variable is promotable.
    if (e is MyException) {
      print(e.code);
    }
  }
}
```